# Как узнать что вернуло if

Tags: c#

Допустим есть чисто прикладная задача: сортировка пузырьком в трехмерном массиве.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Rank; i++)
    {


        for (int j = 0; j < arr1.Rank; j++)
        {

            for (int l = 0; l < arr1.Rank; l++)
            {
                if (arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i-1, j, l]      || arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j-1, l]  || arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j, l-1])
                {
                    byte tmp = arr1[i, j, l];
                    arr1[i, j, l] = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Меня интересует вот эта часть :

```
if (arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i-1, j, l]      || arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j-1, l]  || arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j, l-1])
                {
                    byte tmp = arr1[i, j, l];
                    arr1[i, j, l] =
```

- если я пишу if одной конструкцией -то, что мне подставлять в эту строку `arr1[i, j, l] =` ?  `arr1[i , j-1, l]`  или `arr1[i, j, l]` или  `arr1[i , j,l-1])` ? - т.е. как обратиться непосредственно к if у узнать результат операции в данном случае?

Comment: Разделить на 3 `if`? В чем проблема?

Comment: ок, а в данном случа - не деля на три if -неужели не предусмотрено такой возможности?

Comment: Отлаживать то пробовали? Возможно в "шаг с заходом" вам и покажет что именно было выбрано.

Comment: нет я имею ввиду не отладку а само возвращаемое значение if - т.е одно из условий выполнится - как не разделяя if - подставить возвращаемое значение?

Comment: 'if' ничего не возвращает. Это условный оператор.

Comment: Не, ну в C# 7 (вроде) if может отдавать [out](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables) значение, но там тоже есть свои тонкости...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: `if` ничего не отдает в `out`, это отдает метод который имеет возвращаемый тип `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` - условный оператор, не возвращающий каких-либо значений.

Возможность такое сделать есть, но учтите: ***её использование не является хорошим тоном***.

Вместо использования этого метода рекомендую разделить блок if на 3 блока, содержащих лишь по одному условию. Если часть тела этого if-а используется несколько раз, можно использовать inline функции.

```
int from;
if ((arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i-1, j, l] && Convert.ToBoolean(from = 1)) || (arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j-1, l] && Convert.ToBoolean(from = 2)) || (arr1[i, j, l] < arr1[i , j, l-1] && Convert.ToBoolean(from = 3)))
{
     byte tmp = arr1[i, j, l];
     arr1[i, j, l] = array[i - 1];
     array[i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

При выполнении одного из основных условий (таковыми назовём условия проверки, предоставленные Вами) выполняется дополнительное, цель которого - присвоить значение временной переменной.

Конвертация в `boolean` делается для того, чтобы код работал (`int` не является логическим типом, а с помощью конвертации преобразуется в bool, где всегда означает `true`, главное не присваивать переменной `from` значение `0`, тогда конвертация преобразует его в `false`).

В данном случае временная переменная `from` хранит номер условия, которое "пустило" выполнение в if.

Успехов!

Comment: скорее всего пример не сработает, потому что логические операторы требуют bool а `from` имеет тип int

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Плохое именование переменной `from`, LINQ вас покарает :D

Comment: @Yami да он и так меня постоянно карает XD